# Bind List of objects to a form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-binding

I have a class of `Signature` objects:

```
public class Signature
    {
        public int SignatureID { get; set; }
        public int FormID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Signed Date:")]
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a `Form.cs` class that has a virtual list of signatures

```
public virtual List<Signature> Signatures { get; set; }
```

In my controller, I populate the list by:

```
form.Signatures = repository.Signatures.Where(s => s.FormID == form.FormID).ToList();
```

In my Form View, I display a list of the associated signatures:

```
@foreach (var signature in Model.Signatures)
    {
    <div class="text-center">
        <label asp-for="@signature.Title"></label>
        <input asp-for="@signature.Title" />
        <label asp-for="@signature.Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="@signature.Email" />
        <label asp-for="@signature.Date"></label>
        <input disabled asp-for="@signature.Date">
    </div>
    }
```

However, I don't know how to update the associated signatures upon my POST method of the form. For example, if I change the `Email` property of a signature and POST the form, the model does not bind this change into the `Form` object. In this case, `form.Signatures` is null.

How can I ensure changes to the `<List>Signature` items associated with the form are updated on POST?

Comment: The duplicate doesn't apply...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the `for` loop to generate the elements, as it would add indexing to the property names which is used by model binder to bind to List on the post which does not work with the `foreach`:

```
@for (int i=0; i< Model.Signatures.Count; i++)
{
<div class="text-center">
    <label asp-for="@Model.Signatures[i].Title"></label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.Signatures[i].Title" />
    <label asp-for="@Model.Signatures[i].Email"></label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.Signatures[i].Email" />
    <label asp-for="@Model.Signatures[i].Date"></label>
    <input disabled asp-for="@Model.Signatures[i].Date">
</div>
}
```

Now the elements would be rendered with names like `Signatures[0].Title`, `Signatures[1].Title` and the model binder can bind it to the model on post.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the binding issue. Now I've got to track down a way to call a `save` function in my repo without using an iterative loop because that's causing an error

Comment: glad to help and best of luck.

Comment: One thing to note here is that if an item from the collection can be deleted (i.e: `@Model.Signatures[3]` is deleted entirely by a user) then the collection will not serialize properly. The indexes need to be in a consecutive order beginning at 0

Comment: I would assume that the solution to that would be to use an isDeleted field in the Signature model and use whatever JavaScript/CSS techniques to gray out the input or convey the deleted status. Then when the form is posted, check that isDeleted field and handle it in the persistence tier.